# Django DetailView - How to change the get_object to check a field

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

So I want to make a `DetailView` that shows a photo by itself and its associated information. However, I want to have it make sure the user has permission to access the photo as well.

This is the urls.py for the view

```
url(r'^photo/(?P<slug>[\-\d\w]+)/$', views.PhotoDetail.as_view(), name='photo'),
```

This is the views.py

```
class PhotoDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'otologue/photo_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        slug = self.get_slug_field()
        print(slug)
        object_instance = Photo.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        print(object_instance)
        object_user = object_instance.photoextended.user
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user)  # Get the user in the view

        if object_user != user:  # See if the object_user is the same as the user
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission Error')

        else:
            return object_instance
```

As you can see I try to `get_slug_field()` but when I print it it only says 'slug' when the slug should say the objects slug which is in the url.
From this the object_instance doesn't have any object and then why I try to get the user from it, it can't find any data.

Comment: Note that [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) returns a *queryset* of photos. If you want a single photo you want `Photo.objects.get(slug=slug)` (although this may raise `get_object_or_404`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `DetailView`'s `get_object` method already knows how to fetch an object by the slug. There's no need to duplicate this code, just call `super()`.

Then you can compare the user to `self.request.user` directly - there's no need to refetch the user from the database with `get_object_or_404`.

Finally, you can't return a response from `get_object`, the method is meant to return the object. You can however raise an exception like `Http404`.

```
from django.http import Http404

class PhotoDetail(DetailView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(PhotoDetail, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        if obj.user != obj.photoextended.user:
            raise Http404()
        return obj
```

A common approach in class based views is to override `get_queryset` and filter by user. The `get_object` method will use this queryset when fetching the object. If the object is not in the queryset, then the user will get a 404 error.

```
class PhotoDetail(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PhotoDetail, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(photoextended__user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer seems to work perfectly. I change it to this as it wanted a queryset 'class PhotoDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'otologue/photo_detail.html'
    queryset = Photo.objects

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PhotoDetail, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(photoextended__user=self.request.user)'

Comment: It just seems confusing as to how it manages to get the correct Photo object. Does the queryset automatically look for the slug in the query results and compare it with the slugfield in the url

Comment: The [`get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/145f6c3ed6e8856078e2d04ff2567e9fb4a17930/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20) method starts with the queryset from `get_queryset`, and filters using the slug from the URL to get the object. You might find [ccbv](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) useful to explore how the methods in class based views fit together.